# jquery plugin is not working

Tags: jquery

In my jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/SJFjK/4/

It is supposed to display a scrollbar for my table with fixed headings but it does not show the scrollbar at all, why is this?

I am using the jquery plugin fixheadertable. Below is the code for it.

```
$('#qandatbl').fixheadertable({height: '200'});
```

To add rows onto the table, simply just click on the "Add Question" button multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the plugin.

The error in your JS console should this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fixheadertable'
```

This means that the jQuery object generated by `$('#qandatbl')` doesn't have a `fixheadertable` method on it.  And I can only assume that is because whatever jQuery plugin provides this isn't actually loaded.  Add a script tag on the html window that points to your plugin, in order to use the plugin's methods.